# Using methods with a Template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, methods

I am quite new to C++ and so was wondering if you guys could help me.

I was going through a piece of code and saw a function underneath a template, like this:

```
MyClass(xyzType param1, xyzType param2)
  parameter1 (param1)
 ,parameter2 (param2)
{
    myMethod<ExternalLogicClass>(paramter1, parameter2);

    template<class TemplateClass>
    void MyClass::myMethod(xyzType parameter1, xyzType parameter2)
    {
        xyzType var = xyzObject->createSomething(new TemplateClass(parameter1), parameter2);
    }
};
```

My question is, why would someone do that? `myMethod` could very well have been created without the template. Is there an advantage of using a function with a template, and if yes, then what is the advantage? Also when should it be, and when should it not be used?

Any help is appreciated..
Thank You

Comment: ah, yes.. I'll correct it.. thanks

Comment: *"myMethod could very well have been created without the template"* Could you provide your template-free implementation of `myMethod`?

Comment: Sometimes I use this scheme for debug functions. Cause templates are instantiated only when used I make debug functions as templates and use them adhoc. This way I don't add extra burden on the class it self.

Comment: 'myMethod' well, I tried it without the template, and it works just fine.

Comment: @101010 thats an awesome idea :)

Comment: @ShehrozAlam I can't imagine that it would, how would `new TemplateClass(parameter1)` compile? Is `TemplateClass` also the name of a type?

Comment: ah, no I meant xyzObject->createSomething(parameter1, parameter2).

Comment: @ShehrozAlam This is why an [MCVE] is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I get it now.. it is there, so that it can be used with another class as well, (for example if a class may carry some sort of external logic). Your comment pointed me in the right direction.. THANKS!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I will update the question to make it more clear, but I have my answer anyway.. thanks again

Comment: @101010 that is quite useful.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As posted, `myMethod` does not use any member data of `MyClass`. It could have been implemented as a non-member function template.

```
template<class TemplateClass>
void myMethod(xyzType parameter1, xyzType parameter2)
{
    xyzType var = xyzObject->createSomething(new TemplateClass(parameter1), parameter2);
}
```

However, if `myMethod` depended on some state of `MyClass`, it would make sense to have it as a template member function.

```
MyClass
{
    int myData;

    template<class TemplateClass>
    void myMethod(xyzType parameter1, xyzType parameter2)
    {
        xyzType var = xyzObject->createSomething(new TemplateClass(parameter1),
                                                 parameter2,
                                                 myData); // Member data.
    }
};
```